# when i try to check if a radio button is checked, the code doesnt execute

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, repeater

i am trying 2 make a quiz in asp.net.
the mcq choices r displayed using radio buttons. in code behind, when i try 2 check if radiobutton is checked, d code under that if statement does not execute. 
**aspx code:**

```
<ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ques") %>'></asp:Literal><br />
            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton1" Text='<%#Eval("ch1") %>' runat="server" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton2" Text='<%#Eval("ch2") %>' runat="server" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton3" Text='<%#Eval("ch3") %>' runat="server" /><br />
            <asp:RadioButton GroupName="a" ID="RadioButton4" Text='<%#Eval("ch4") %>' runat="server" /><br />

            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ans") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
```

**code behind:**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 0;

        foreach(RepeaterItem Items in Repeater1.Items)
        {

            RadioButton r1 = (RadioButton)Items.FindControl("RadioButton1");
            RadioButton r2 = (RadioButton)Items.FindControl("RadioButton2");
            RadioButton r3 = (RadioButton)Items.FindControl("RadioButton3");
            RadioButton r4 = (RadioButton)Items.FindControl("RadioButton4");
            Label l3 = (Label)Items.FindControl("Label3");

            Label l=(Label)Items.FindControl("Label1");
            l3.Text = "hello?";
            if (r1.Checked)
            {
               if(r1.Text==l.Text)
                     count++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (r2.Checked)
                {
                    if(r2.Text==l.Text)
                       count++;
                }
            }
              // and so on for all 4 options
        }
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label2.Text = "your score is " + count;       //always zero!

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're stepping through the debugger, and your line

```
if(r1.Text==l.Text) 
  count++;
```

isn't executing, then I would guess that the line `if (r1.Checked)` is evaluating to false.

On your `Page_Load()` method for this page, are there any databindings or manipulation of these radio buttons?  If so, unless you wrap them in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack){ ... }` conditional then it will wipe out whatever the user did to the radio button, hence `r1.Checked` would be `false`.

I hope that might help :) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do the following:

1. Set the `AutoPostBack` on the radio button control to true.
2. Set the `OnItemCommand` on the repeater control to "Button1_Click"
3. Change the signature of the Button1_Click method to `protected void Button1_Click(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)`

That will at least trigger the method in your code behind.